# Find real size of Windows/winsxs folder in Cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, hardlink, winsxs

I'm running Cygwin with the default installation. I'm a complete noobie to Linux & Cygwin. I just figured out how to find all hardlinked files in my c:\windows\winsxs folder. (Navigate to **`/cygdrive/c/windows/winsxs`** and type **`find . -links +1`**) Can Cygwin calculate the true size of the Winsxs folder? Windows reports it at 8.62GB, but I know there are multiple hardlinked files. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually the size you report actually sounds correct.  You do understand the WinSXS will grow and shrink has needed right?

Comment: Everyone's winsxs folder will be different in reported size. It does grow with installed programs/windows updates. But... TreeSize Free says all the data on the partition is just under 300MB shy of the partition size, yet I have 3.00GB free. (See pic at http://stephen.yi.org/treesize.png ) I don't use any sort of compression, so it must be hardlinked files that are causing this. I've read in many places that there are hardlinks in the winsxs folder, as Cygwin has also demonstrated.

Comment: But your actual disk usage of WinSXS wont change with those hard links so knowing how large it is wont change the size because most actions that would reduce it would be harmful